# Deploy multiple ASP .NET applications to single Elastic Beanstalk application

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two ASP .NET applications, one is we can say 'frontend' and second is 'backend' for that frontend.

Using AWS Toolkit in Visual Studio I can right click and Publish 'frontend' to Elastic Beanstalk application. It auto generates instance for it etc. And now how can I deploy my 'backend' to the same instance?

I want the URL's to be like http://..ipaddress and http://..ipaddress/admin. The application is dependent on each other, so I cannot run them on separate instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just released multi app support for the Elastic Beanstalk Windows container. I wrote this blog post to help explain how it works.

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx29MH65I0HLAN5/Multiple-Application-Support-for-NET-and-Elastic-Beanstalk

Comment: Hello, is it possible to do the same flow, but using a node.js and a python (flask) app?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I don't know the node.js and python Beanstalk solution stacks. This comment was for a feature we specifically added to the Windows container.